# Datepicker is not working on icon click for img field

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have added all the required js files as below

```
<script src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery-1.12.3.js'/>"  
type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/static/js/bootstrap.min.js' />" 
type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src="<c:url value='/static/js/jquery-ui.js' />" 
type='text/javascript'></script>
```

but the datepicker block simply does not work.

```
<script>
$(function () {  
    $("#txtdate").datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Thats the html code below

```
<td> <input type="date" id="txtdate" value="{{plan.startDate}}" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"/>
```

Comment: _simply does not work_ -- which part doesn't work exactly? Do you receive any error in console?

Comment: Any error in `console` ?

Comment: You should be careful when using Bootstrap and jQueryUI together - they often have conflicts. I'd suggest removing one of them.

Comment: i commented out the bootstrap.min.js, but there is no change.The code above does open up the calendar but any format changes I try to provide in the script, no change is applied.Next I needed the input field with type='text' and an icon next to it which shall open the calendar.Tried with many options found on sites but there is no change applied through the script. `$("#txtdate").datepicker();` part does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the issue is with the `date` type. This will create a HTML based picker to be created by the browser. This will conflict with the jQuery UI Datepicker.

> Creating a datepicker on an `<input type="date">` is not supported due to a UI conflict with the native picker.

To address this, I would advise using `text` type.

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/5pk37jav/

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="txtdate" value="2017/11/01" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $("#txtdate").datepicker();
});
```

This will ensure that there is not a conflict and the code you want executed is running.